# Getting Error 500 in SMTP sampler in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, smtp

I am getting this error while running the SMTP Sampler in JMeter:
**Response code: 500

Response message: IOException while sending message**

And I got the following in the logs:

> javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message  at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1167)
>   ~[mail-1.5.0-b01.jar:1.5.0-b01]   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.protocol.SendMailCommand.execute(SendMailCommand.java:303)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_mail.jar:3.2 r1790748]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.SmtpSampler.executeMessage(SmtpSampler.java:169)
>   [ApacheJMeter_mail.jar:3.2 r1790748]  at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.SmtpSampler.sample(SmtpSampler.java:146)
>   [ApacheJMeter_mail.jar:3.2 r1790748]  at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:491)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]  at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:425)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]  at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source) [?:1.8.0_201] Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: V:\001
>   Automation\Automation Scripts\Test Plan\Cloud\Final\Priority 6 -
>   Process (Access is denied)    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native
>   Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]

What would probably the cause of the issue and how it will be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message JMeter cannot access the following file:

```
V:\001 Automation\Automation Scripts\Test Plan\Cloud\Final\Priority 6 - Process
```

make sure to [amend the permissions to the file](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-take-ownership-files-and-folders-windows-10) and make sure the user account under which you're running JMeter has access to the given file.

Also be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1) (or whatever is the latest stable version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) as soon as possible.

Comment: do we always require to have an attachment?

Comment: It's up to you actually, it depends on the test scenario you're executing. From the SMTP Sampler's perspective the attachment is not mandatory, i.e. you can send a plain-text message or even empty message. Check out [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article for more details.

Comment: I actually bypass the issue when i added attachment. When i removed it, then that issue was encountered